# How to pass default value as 0 but not to reflect in HTML

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I am working in angular and I am passing 0 as default value in reactive form formControl. The default value is getting reflected in the HTML input. I dont want to show default value in HTML input field at first.

How can I achieve that ?

```
carnumbers: new FormControl('0', [Validators.minLength(1), Validators.maxLength(2), Validators.pattern("^[0-9]*$")])
```

*Note: the default value must be 0*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want show default value in View, you should use **[setValue](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormControl#setValue)** or **patchValue** on formControl and pass **emitModelToViewChange:false** options to it.

```
 carnumbers = new FormControl(null, [Validators.minLength(1), 
     Validators.maxLength(2), Validators.pattern("^[0-9]*$")]);

  ngAfterViewInit(){ 
      this.carnumbers.setValue(0,{emitModelToViewChange:false});
  }
```

**[Working Simple Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-656nvq?file=src/app/app.component.ts)**

Comment: One problem in this. if I go forward to other page then again coming back I am patching the values  and do submit then  `ngAfterViewInit` setting up all values to 0.

Comment: you means submit function triggered even before ngAfterViewINit?

Comment: No, suppose I have submitted the detail and when coming back to this screen, the value which I have submitted I am patching it. But when again I click submit it is setting the value to 0. So, when I commented out `this.carnumbers.setValue(0,{emitModelToViewChange:false});` it was passing patched value again.

Comment: Can't you patch the submit value inside ngAfterViewInit hook?

Comment: I am checking with that

Answer (score 1):

Use `null` or `''` and change that to your default values as a preprocess step before submitting the form.

Comment: This. Don't use a default value (could use placeholder tho if you want) and appent the default value manually before submitting the form when it's still empty, null or undefined.